# Create a diagram venn

Tags: python, r, awk, venn-diagram

I would like to know if you can help me.
I want to make a venn diagram with the presence and absence data (.Rtab) of roary (example fragment, the real list is about 8000 genes):

```
Gene    StrainA StrainB StrainC
group_633   1   0   1
group_644   1   0   1
group_669   1   0   1
ybeZ    1   1   1
maeB    1   1   1
smc_4   1   0   1
cas4-cas1   1   1   1
group_813   0   1   1
group_844   1   1   1
group_854   1   0   0
group_45    0   0   0
group_124   0   0   1
group_323   0   1   0
```

How can I delete the rows where the following pattern appears?

```
`name 0 0 0`
```

For Venn diagram:

The core gene is:

```
`name 1 1 1`
```

Accessory a+b:

```
`name 1 1 0`
```

Accessory b+c:

```
`name 0 1 1`
```

Accessories a+c:

```
`name 1 0 1`
```

unique a:

```
`name 1 0 0`
```

unique b:

```
`name 0 1 0`
```

unique c:

```
`name 0 0 1`
```

Thanks

Me gustaria poder resolverlo con awk o Rstudio o another tool

Answer (score 1):

In r you can do it with the package `VennDiagram`
see ?venn.diagram or https://r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm.html for customization

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(VennDiagram)
df=tribble(~Gene,    ~StrainA, ~StrainB, ~StrainC,
        "group_633",   1,   0,   1,
        "group_644",   1,   0,   1,
        "group_669",   1,   0,   1,
        "ybeZ",    1,   1,   1,
        "maeB",    1,   1,   1,
        "smc_4",   1,   0,   1,
        "cas4-cas1",   1,   1,   1,
        "group_813",   0,  1,   1,
        "group_844",   1,   1,   1,
        "group_854",   1,   0,   0,
        "group_45",    0,   0,   0,
        "group_124",   0,   0,   1,
        "group_323",   0,   1,   0)

# 1. How can I delete the rows where the following pattern appears? `name 0 0 0`
df2=df%>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(StrainA:StrainC)))%>%
  filter(sum!=0)%>%
  select(-sum)

StrainA=df2%>%filter(StrainA==1)%>%pull(Gene)
StrainB=df2%>%filter(StrainB==1)%>%pull(Gene)
StrainC=df2%>%filter(StrainC==1)%>%pull(Gene)

venn.diagram(
  x = list(StrainA, StrainB, StrainC),
  category.names = c("StrainA" , "StrainB" , "StrainC"),
  filename = 'my_venn.tiff',
  output=TRUE
)
#> [1] 1
```

my_venn.tiff file
[image: my_venn]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could give this bit of Python a go:

```py
filename = 'input_file.Rtab'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Filter down the data
data = [line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in lines if not line.rstrip().split('\t')[1:] == ['0', '0', '0']]

# Define a mapping from (a, b, c) to the category name
category_mapping = {
    ('1', '1', '1'): 'core',
    ('1', '1', '0'): 'acc_a_b',
    ('0', '1', '1'): 'acc_b_c',
    ('1', '0', '1'): 'acc_a_c',
    ('1', '0', '0'): 'unique_a',
    ('0', '1', '0'): 'unique_b',
    ('0', '0', '1'): 'unique_c'
}

# Initialize the dictionary with empty lists using the category names from category_mapping
venn_dict = {category: [] for category in category_mapping.values()}

# Process the data and populate the dictionary
for line in data:
    name, a, b, c = line
    category = category_mapping.get((a, b, c))
    if category:
        venn_dict[category].append(name)

# Print the resulting dictionary
print(venn_dict)
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and response,

I ran that and it gave me error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/venn.py", line 25, in <module>.
    nombre, a, b, c = línea
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: It appears that one or more of your lines doesn't contain a tab. Are your columns separated by tabs? Stackoverflow formatted it to spaces in your question if they are tabs, I figured that they were tabs. If for some reason there are any lines in your code that aren't formatted that way and you just want to ignore them, change the assignment of ```data``` to the following to check to see if the row has four columns:

```data = [line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in lines if not line.rstrip().split('\t')[1:] == ['0', '0', '0'] and len(line.rstrip().split('\t')) == 4]```

Comment: I made the change in "data" that you say and I got this: {'core': ['mtgA_1', 'acdA_2', 'wbpE', 'mshA_2', 'group_1033', 'group_1035', 'mrr', 'group_1037', 'purC', 'purS', 'group_1041', 'orfC', 'yfcG', 'ccmF', 'ccmE', 'dapA', 'group_1052', 'group_1061', 'adh', 'kdpD', 'group_1075', 'group_1076', 'pyrE_1', 'group_1081', 'group_1083', 'icmF_1', 'group_1094', 'group_1096', 'arnC_6', 'fliP', 'bepA_7', 'group_1113', 'hisD', 'group_1115', 'rpsP', 'group_1118', 'group_1121', 'group_1122', 'group_1123', 'group_1127'

Comment: @bio_BATMAN Is there any way that you could post your input file to pastebin.com and share the link, or maybe a shortened version of the file? I'm not sure how your input is formatted, I think Stack Overflow might be changing how your example for your input file is formatted. I tried an example using tabs to separate the columns and it works on my end.

Comment: ok, yes. The link is https://pastelink.net/7ool2ca9

Comment: Okay, this indicates that you're using spaces to separate your columns. Replace the data assignment with this:

```data = [line.rstrip().split(' ') for line in lines if not line.rstrip().split(' ')[1:] == ['0', '0', '0'] and len(line.rstrip().split(' ')) == 4]```

Though I'm not sure how you got the output you described after the first change to ```data```, I couldn't get that output. Are you sure your whole file is formatted like you put on Pastebin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253319/discussion-between-brock-brown-and-bio-batman).